# The use of the modal verb "would" in context

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

Tell me please if the following sentence is gramatically correct.

> John, would not it be better to visit Rachel tommorow, if it would not, then could you please explain why?

What I am in doubt about is the use of *would* after *if*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem using **would** after **if**.

But the construction **would not it** is most unusual. In fact, a quick Ngram check found no usages of it all. The usual construction is **would it not**.

That aside, you need either a semi-colon or a full-stop after tomorrow to break up your sentence.

> John, would it not be better to visit Rachel tommorow? If it would not (be better), then could you please explain why?

Note that the use of **be better** in the second sentence is understood.

Alternatively you could simplify the sentence and omit the words **it would** and **then** altogether in the second sentence.

> John, would it not be better to visit Rachel tommorow; if not, could you please explain why?

This is the form that most people would be likely to use. But you will often hear people saying things like:

> If you would be kind enough.....

or

> If you would consider going...

And there's no problem with this construction.

Comment: Great answer as always! Could I just point you to [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/169617/how-often-is-the-expression-get-on-well-used-is-there-any-difference-with-ge/169642#comment339358_169642) because I've noticed that even though people have started using the tool, they have fallen under a couple of misapprehensions regarding the terminology used to describe it/the results it produces. In summary, the tool can be unambiguously referenced as *Google Books Ngram Viewer* (don't worry, I don't work for Google); it plots a chart of frequencies of n-grams over time.

Comment: Also, see [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/166253/3395) and [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/167783/3395). *Would not it* is unusual because it's ungrammatical.

Comment: Whilst "would not it" is unusual, it's worth noting that "wouldn't it" is actually very common (at least in spoken English).

Comment: @userr2684291 I wasn't certain whether there might be a legitimate construction that incorporated **would not it**.  My several efforts to link a (Google Books) Ngram Viewer have come to naught. Quick guide source would be appreciated.

Comment: @RonaldSole Both the answers I linked you to above answer that exact question (regarding why it's unusual).

Comment: **would not it {verb}** is a licit formal construction, but it's avoided nowadays. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22would%20not%20it%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en